# File Upload Issues in Jersey RestFull Service

Tags: java, file-upload, jersey

I'm using jersey as backend in one of my applications. I am having trouble in uplaoding file using jersey. I have used the common file upload code available on google.

```
@POST
@Path("/setProfileImage")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String setProfileImage(
            @FormDataParam("profileimage") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            @QueryParam("myemail") String myemail) throws IOException {

        String contextRoot = uri.getBaseUri().getPath();
        String uploadedFileLocationOrig = httpRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("")  + "/images/" + myemail + "_orig.png";       
        FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(uploadedInputStream, new File(uploadedFileLocationOrig));

            return "true";
    }
```

The code runs without error, but the image copied at the destination is not valid and an empty file is returned when I hit this file using its url.

[image: error]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out, the `version` of `Jersey` was pretty old i.e. `1.17` and following code worked like a charm for me

```
@POST
@Path("/setProfileImage")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public String setProfileImage(
    final MimeMultipart file,
    @QueryParam("myemail") String myemail) throws IOException, javax.mail.MessagingException {

    String uploadedFileLocationOrig = httpRequest.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("")  + "/images/" + myemail + "_orig.png";

    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(file.getBodyPart(0).getInputStream(), new File(uploadedFileLocationOrig));

    return "true";
}
```